# Integration between MSTest, Specflow and Serenity

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, specflow

#### Introduction

After a long struggle i finally found out how to run my specflow scenario's through the MSTest Runner. However i could not find a convenient way of showing the test results in the orderly overview that many BDD books and courses promote.

#### What i've tried so far

The way i currently generate my reports is with the following CMD commands, executed in the Visual Studio Dev CMD.

> #### generic
>
> "navigate\to\specific\visual\studio\folder\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:"navigate\to\test\dll\relative\to\mstest" /resultsfile:\folder\in\my\project\result.html
>
> "navigate\to\specific\specflow\folder\in\project\specflow.exe mstestexecutionreport "absolute\path\to\my\csproj\file\under\test" /testResult:relative\directory\in\project\testResults.trx /out:directory\relative\in\project\TestResults.html
>
> #### my specific unreadable (obfuscated) case
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:"C:\Workspace\Branch\Sub1\Sub2a\Project\bin\Debug\Project.dll" /resultsfile:\Sub2a\TestResults\TestResults.trx
> "C:\Workspace\Branch\Sub1\Sub2b\SpecFlow.2.0.0\tools\specflow.exe" mstestexecutionreport "C:\Workspace\Branch\Sub1\sub2a\Project\Project.csproj" /testResult:Sub1\TestResults\TestResults.trx /out:Sub1\TestResults\TestResults.html

I probably don't have to mention how tighlty coupled this script is to my specific machine, workspace, project, visual studio version and tests.

There must be some way to make these tools work better with a more generic script or some kind of plugin for the mstest report without going through so much cmd line statements with huge parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is using MSTest a hard criteria? If not, have a look at the reporting features of the SpecFlow+Runner. http://www.specflow.org/plus/

Comment: Unfortunatly yes, i've also tried using NUnit to no avail. I did not choose the application framework or structure myself and this testrunner is currently used to run the other unit tests. Using the SpecFlow+Runner would indeed be easier but the company could not afford this right now.